# How to convert byte[] to bytebuffer native memory?

Tags: java, performance, java-native-interface, arrays, bytebuffer

I need pass a large amount memory to jni side to parse it.
I used GetByteArrayElements to get the native pointer before.but i found this method is always copy the memory,not using the memory directly.
So i use GetDirectBufferAddress to get memory directly to avoid mem copy.
This require that one must use allocateDirect method to allocate memory.
But the memory gived to me is byte array, not native memory.
Is there some way to convert byte[] to bytebuffer?
Thanks.

Comment: You are taking data and moving from within the VM (primitive array) to a place outside of the VM (native OS memory space) -- unfortunately that requires the copy operation as the data transitions over that "blood-brain" barrier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, you will have to use [put](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#put%28byte%5B%5D%29) and copy your byte array to the buffer allocated with `allocateDirect`.

Comment: That is really really unfortunately.The memory copy can not be avoid,on java side or jni side.